# Does moon's light splits in seven colours?

Tags: optics, visible-light, astrophysics, reflection, moon

I clicked this pic of supermoon2016 and the light around it splitted into seven colours.was it my camera's effect or it was moon light which was scattered into seven colours. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is no such thing as moonlight as it just reflects the sun light which is divided into 7 colors so you will see the light reflected from moon also splitted into 7.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, because moons light is not actually it's own light.
it is just reflection of sun light.And we know that the light comes from sun can splitted into 7 colours.Hence, so called moon light be splitted into 7 colours

Answer (score -2):

Moon light is composed of seven colors because it is warm and white glow. When white light glow under scattering in the form of "VIBGYOR".